# What is the gradient of $\frac{1}{|x|}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Given a function $V(x)$:
$$\displaystyle V(x) =  \frac {1}{||x||}$$
What is the gradient, $\nabla V$, of $V$?

The result I saw is: $\displaystyle -\frac {x}{||x||^3}$.

How do I get this?

Comment: You should complete the question showing what you have tried.

Comment: More explicitly, $V(x_1,\dots, x_n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x_1)^2+\cdots +(x_n)^2}}$. I'm sure using the quotient rule and standard rules of differentiation, you can calculate $\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_i}$

Comment: Hint, how do you calculate the magnitude of a vector given it's coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first rename your function like so:
$$
f(\vec{\bf{v}})=\frac{1}{||\vec{\bf{v}}||}
$$
We can then name each component of your vector $\vec{\bf{v}}_x$ and $\vec{\bf{v}}_y$, and have them as the individual parameters of the function and given that $||\vec{\bf{v}}||=\sqrt{\left(\vec{\bf{v}}_x\right)^2+\left(\vec{\bf{v}}_y\right)^2}$:
$$
\begin{align}
& f(\vec{\bf{v}}_x,\vec{\bf{v}}_y)=\frac{1}{||\vec{\bf{v}}||} \\
\implies & f(\vec{\bf{v}}_x,\vec{\bf{v}}_y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\vec{\bf{v}}_x\right)^2+\left(\vec{\bf{v}}_y\right)^2}}
\end{align}
$$
Now we can differentiate this with respect to $\vec{\bf{v}}_x$ or $\vec{\bf{v}}_y$ like so:
$$
\begin{align}
&f(\vec{\bf{v}}_x,\vec{\bf{v}}_y)=\left(\left(\vec{\bf{v}}_x\right)^2+\left(\vec{\bf{v}}_y\right)^2\right)^\frac{-1}{2} \\
&\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{\bf{v}}_x} = \frac{-1}{2}\left(\left(\vec{\bf{v}}_x\right)^2+\left(\vec{\bf{v}}_y\right)^2\right)^\frac{-3}{2}\cdot\frac{\partial \left(\left(\vec{\bf{v}}_x\right)^2+\left(\vec{\bf{v}}_y\right)^2\right)}{\partial \vec{\bf{v}}_x} \\
&\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{\bf{v}}_x} = \frac{-1}{2}\left(\left(\vec{\bf{v}}_x\right)^2+\left(\vec{\bf{v}}_y\right)^2\right)^\frac{-3}{2}\cdot 2 \vec{\bf{v}}_x \\
&\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{\bf{v}}_x} = \frac{-2\vec{\bf{v}}_x}{2}\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{\left(\vec{\bf{v}}_x\right)^2+\left(\vec{\bf{v}}_y\right)^2}\right)^3} \\
&\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{\bf{v}}_x} = \boxed{\frac{-\vec{\bf{v}}_x}{\left(\sqrt{\left(\vec{\bf{v}}_x\right)^2+\left(\vec{\bf{v}}_y\right)^2}\right)^3}}
\end{align}
$$
Which simplifies to:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{\bf{v}}_x} = \boxed{\frac{-\vec{\bf{v}}_x}{||\vec{\bf{v}}||^3}}
$$
And the same for differentiating with respect to $\vec{\bf{v}}_y$. So the gradient of your function is:
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla f &=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-\vec{\bf{v}}_x}{||\vec{\bf{v}}||^3} \\
\frac{-\vec{\bf{v}}_y}{||\vec{\bf{v}}||^3}
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=\frac{-1}{||\vec{\bf{v}}||^3}\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{\bf{v}}_x \\
\vec{\bf{v}}_y
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=\frac{-1}{||\vec{\bf{v}}||^3}\vec{\bf{v}} \\
&=\boxed{-\frac{\vec{\bf{v}}}{||\vec{\bf{v}}||^3}}
\end{align}
$$

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 2):

Using the definition of vector norm $||x||=\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i}{x_i^2}}$, we have, $\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_i}=-\frac{1}{||x||^2}.\frac{1}{2||x||}.2x_i$, by chain rule. Hence, $\nabla V=\left[-\frac{x_1}{||x||^3}, -\frac{x_2}{||x||^3}, \ldots\right]^T=-\frac{x}{||x||^3}$.